# Typescript, Angular2, HTML convert string PDF and display as image

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, typescript

Hey there i have the following problem im getting a long string including a PDF. Im convertign the string into a BLOB using

```
let byteCharacters = atob(pdfData);
let byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
let bytearray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
this.file = new Blob([bytearray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
let unsafeURL: any = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
this.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(unsafeURL);
```

after this conversion currently display it as a normal PDF

```
<iframe class="pdfRendered" [src]="fileURL" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But this is **NOT** they way i want it, because it looks on my site like an PDF.
I want to display it like an image or something the user cannot print, zoom and navigate.

Is there any way to convert it to PDF on Typescript and right after that to an image or just display the pdf like an image on my HTML?

Comment: anyone some ideas?